# How to subset sequences in fasta file based on sequence ID or Name?

Tags: r, subset

I have set of EST sequences in fasta file. Here, how to subset based on sequence ID or name?

```
>gi|296783888|gb|GW992815.1|GW992815 UAS-Mi10 Complementary DNA of mulberry (Morus indica) Morus indica cDNA 5' similar to Putative phosphoribosyltransferase/phosphoribosylanthranilate-like gene from Morus indica, mRNA sequence
GCAGCCGTCGGATCGTGAGCGTGATCGCGTGGCTAGTCGGGTTGGCGAAATGGTTGGATGATATCCGGAG
GTGGAGGAACCCCATTACCACGGTATTGGTCCACATCTTATATTTAGTGCTTGTTTGGTACCCGGATTTG
ATTGTCCCAACCGGGTTTTTATATGTGTTCCTAATCGGTGTATGGTACTATCGGTTTCGGCCCAAGATAC
CAGCGGGTATGGATACCCGACTCTCACAAGCTGAAGCGGTTGACCCGGATGAGCTTGATGAGGAATTCGA
CACCATACCGAGCTCAAAACCACCCGACATAATCAGGGTCCGGTATGACCGGTTGCGGATATTGGCAGCC
CGGGTTCAAACGGTTTTGGGTGATTTTGCAACACAAGGGGAGCGGGTTCAGGCCTTGGTTAGCTGGAGGG
ACCCAAGGGCCACAAAATTGTTCATAGGCGTGTGCTTGGCCATAACAATAATTCTCTATGTGGTGCCACC
CAAAATGGTTGCCGTGGCACTTGGATTCTACTATTTACGACACCCCATGTTCCGAGACCCCATGCCTCCT
GCAAGCTTGAATTTCTTCAGAAGGCTTCCAAGCCTTTCAGACCGCTTTAATGTAGATTAGAATATTATAT
GATTATTAGTAGGCCCAA

>gi|296783887|gb|GW992814.1|GW992814 UAS-Mi9 Complementary DNA of mulberry (Morus indica) Morus indica cDNA 5' similar to Dehydration-responsive protein RD22, Similar to BURP domain-containing protein like gene from Morus indica, mRNA sequence
AAGCAGTGGTCTAGAACCAGAGTGGCCCCTGCGATGCAGGTATCATCTCTATTATCAAAAGGGATAAGGG
GTGGATCCGTCGGGGATTTGAGTCTCACATGGTCGCTGATAACTTATTGAATGGATATTGGATTGTGTGC
AGTGCGACCTAAACAGGATTGCCGTTGGGGCCTGTGGTCAGAGATACCCCACACTTCTCAACTCCCAAAT
TGGATCTTGTTCCTTGTTTTCCTGTATTAAGCCTGACCCCTGAGGCTTTCGCCACTGCCAACTGGGTGCC
GCCTGCTGACTTCTGATTCCCCGTGCTAACGGTTACTCCCGATTCCTTATCCACATCGAAGATGAACTAT
TGACTTCCGCAAACTCAAAAGGCTGCAAGATATCACTGACCGCTGTCGGGATCCGCGATCGGCATATACG
CGAAATCCGATCCCGGATCCCGGGACTGCAGACGGCTGAA
```

Like using header line `>gi|296783888|gb|GW992815.1|GW992815 UAS-Mi10 Complementary DNA of mulberry (Morus indica) Morus indica cDNA 5' similar to Putative phosphoribosyltransferase/phosphoribosylanthranilate-like gene from Morus indica, mRNA sequence` or using only `>gi|296783888` 
How to do this in R?

Comment: Does `strsplit(text, ">gi")` work?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: Actaully i used `read.fasta` function in `seqinr` package to read input file. As you mentioned i tried but the error is `Error in strsplit(p, ">gi|296783888") : non-character argument`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For a slightly more heavy-weight solution, if this fits in to the Bioconductor work flow,

```
source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("Rsamtools")
```

to install the Biostrings and Rsamtools package, then

```
library(Rsamtools)
indexFa("foo.fasta")   # create an index of file 'foo.fasta'
fa = FaFile("foo.fasta")  # reference the fasta file and it's index
```

You can discover the coordinates (names and start / end) of each sequence with

```
gr = as(seqinfo(fa), "GRanges")
```

and query for arbitrary sequences and ranges within sequences by choosing appropriate subsets, e.g., the second sequence and then first sequence in your example

```
getSeq(fa, gr[2:1])
```

or by looking up the coordinates by partial match to the names

```
idx = pmatch("gi|296783888", names(gr))  ## NA's if duplicates or not unique
seq = getSeq(fa, gr[idx])
```

"seq" is a DNAStringSet, and can be manipulated in many ways; see the vignettes available in the package

```
vignette(package="Biostrings")
```

especially the [Quick Overview](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/Biostrings/inst/doc/BiostringsQuickOverview.pdf). To save the object to a fasta file 'file.fa' in a directory 'some' relative to the current working directory, use

```
writeXStringSet(seq, "some/file.fa")
```

Comment: I tried your suggestions, it worked for my sample files, when i moved to larger files, I got the following error `Warning messages:
1: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  [fai_build_core] different line length in sequence 'LA11031.CleanEST.seq.Contig60'.
2: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  [fai_load] fail to open FASTA index.
Error in indexFa(open(FaFile(file))) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'file' in selecting a method for function 'indexFa': Error in value[[3L]](cond) : 'open' index failed
  file: mulberry.fasta`.

Comment: I found out, when extra empty line is added after sequences, I am getting this warning. How to format and remove these empty lines automatically in multi-fasta file?

Comment: Maybe an easy way to correctly format the input is to read the entire file `dna = Biostrings::readDNAStringSet("tmp.fa")` then write it out again `Biostrings::writeXStringSet(dna, "tmp1.fa")`; "tmp1.fa" is then correctly formatted for indexing.

Comment: Many thanks, I will try your suggestion. 1 more thing, if i get NAs in idx, the error message is `Error in scanFa(x, param, ...) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'param' in selecting a method for function 'scanFa': Error in IRanges:::normalizeSingleBracketSubscript(i, x) : 
  subscript contains NAs or out of bounds indices`, how to handle this? using, `idx <- idx[ !is.na( idx ) ]` is ok? its working well!

Comment: 1 more problem is, how to write fasta file?, I have tried `write.fasta(sequences = seq(seqq), names = names(seqq), file.out ="finalfile.fasta")` but the result is only the sequence name and something like serial numbers of sequences.

Comment: Depending on what type of object `idx` is, perhaps you want na.omit(idx). I updated the answer to indicate how to output DNAStringSet objects.

Comment: Thank you for your edit. I think, there is a typo,`writeXStringSet(seq, "some/file.fa")` to be `writeXStringSet(seq, "somefile.fa")`

Comment: An extemporaneous question: does Rsamtools work on protein fasta?

Comment: @gunzapper Yes, add the argument `as="AAStringSet"` to `getSeq()`. Also use `Biostrings::readAAStringSet()`.